# Frequent error in Oracle ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

We're getting this error once a day on a script that runs every two hours, but at different times of the day.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04061: existing state of package body "PACKAGE.NAME" has been
invalidated
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"PACKAGE.NAME"
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Could someone list what conditions can cause this error so that we could investigate?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
 Would executing `'ALTER SESSION CLOSE  DATABASE LINK DBLINK'` invalidate a state of the package?

Comment: Just as a further piece of information, compiling the package body doesn't make the calling packages "go invalid" - i.e. the data dictionary will still show all packages and triggers and whatever as "VALID". The thing that goes invalid is each user's PGA. So if there are ten users using the package as it's recompiled then each will hit this problem in turn the next time they reference that package.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This one liner actually solved everything:

```
PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;
```

Be sure that your global variables are stateless to avoid any issues.

Comment: to be more precise, this pragma causes the package state to be reset on each request to the database (package initialization is executed again).

Comment: This pragma can't solve "everything". It's appropriate only for specific use cases.

Answer (score 17):

The package has public or private variables. (Right?) This variables form the state a the package. If you compile the package in 3rd session. The next access to this package will throw the ORA-04068.

The build timestamp of a package must be older than the package session state.

If the package state is not needed for script running, the call `DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE` at the beginning of your script. This cleans all package states of your session.

Comment: Will try the specified call. Thanks.

Comment: A question though, how does compiling a package in the 3rd session invalidate it?

Comment: martilyo: the new version of the package could have more/less/other package variables. In fact, if you compile a package that has no package variables at all, those ORA-04068 errors do not happen. Daredevils do that on production systems, during busy work hours..

Comment: Would executing 'ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK DBLINK' invalidate a state of the package?

Answer (score 5):

You may also check `dba_dependencies` or `user_dependencies`.

```
select *
from dba_dependencies
where name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE'
and type = 'PACKAGE' --- or 'PACKAGE_BODY'
and owner = USER --- or USERNAME
```

This will give you the objects your package is dependent on. Check whats happening in there.

Answer (score 3):

We have had this issues for couple of times and for time being, we were compiling schema to resolve this issue temporarily. Over couple of days we were searching for the permanent resolution.

We found below query that showed timestamp difference in our synonym. we recompiled synonym and It worked !!! It's been almost a week and so far we have no issues. Here is the query that helped in our case.

**

```
select do.obj# d_obj,do.name d_name, do.type# d_type, po.obj# p_obj,po.name p_name,
to_char(p_timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "P_Timestamp",
to_char(po.stime ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "STIME", 
decode(sign(po.stime-p_timestamp),0,'SAME','*DIFFER*') X 
from sys.obj$ do, sys.dependency$ d, sys.obj$ po
where P_OBJ#=po.obj#(+) and D_OBJ#=do.obj# 
and do.status=1 /*dependent is valid*/ 
and po.status=1 /*parent is valid*/ 
and po.stime!=p_timestamp /*parent timestamp not match*/ 
order by 2,1;
```

**

I hope this helps someone who may be having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are making changes to your objects that make other objects invalid. Droping an index for example can put into an invalid state all the packages that dependes on that table. It can have a cascade efect. If the package is invalid, the funciton that depends on the package and the view that uses the function can become invalid. Try to recompile all the objects after every DDL query.