# Why Can't I execute same procedure from tomcat datasource?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, groovy, datasource

I have the following issue:

I'm trying to execute a procedure that is part of a package. I can execute the procedure once, but when this has not finished yet and I trigger other execution of the same procedure, the connection return an Invalid Status:

```
SQLERR: -4061. SQLERRM: ORA-04061: existing state of  has been invalidated
```

When the procedure is finished and I trigger the procedure again, it works successfully. I'm connecting from a Application developed with Groovy running over a Tomcat Server with a Tomcat Data Source.

Comment: Please show the code of the procedure in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-04061: existing state of package body "PACKAGE.NAME" has been invalidated persists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387461/ora-04061-existing-state-of-package-body-package-name-has-been-invalidated-pe)